# apacite+natbib in lyx: always error "too many }'s"

Tags: lyx, natbib, apa-style

I spent the last hours breaking my head and the internet over what is wrong with using `apacite` and `natbib` in `lyx` (since I seem not to be the only one...). Here is what I did:

- in settings - literature checked `natbib` (author year)
- in latex preamble wrote

`\usepackage[english]{babel}`

`\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}`

I get the following error:

```
with or without a funny code with all kinds of brackets, i always get the error: "Too many }'s"        \let\fi\fi}
                        {}%
You've closed more groups than you opened.
Such booboos are generally harmless, so keep going.
```

This is the mwe:

```
\lyxformat 474 
\begin_document 
\begin_header 
\textclass scrbook 
\begin_preamble 
\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\bibpunct{(}{)}{,}{a}{,}{,} 
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite} 
\end_preamble 
\use_default_options true 
\maintain_unincluded_children false 
\language american 
\language_package default 
\inputencoding auto 
\fontencoding global ... 
\bibtex_command bibtex 
\index_command default 
\paperfontsize default 
\spacing single 
\use_hyperref false ... 
\cite_engine natbib 
\cite_engine_type authoryear 
\biblio_style apacite 
\use_bibtopic false 
\use_indices false 
\paperorientation portrait
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)? See [LyX user questions on TeX stackexchange](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4488/lyx-user-questions-on-tex-stackexchange) for help on creating a MWE when you are using LyX.

Comment: \lyxformat 474
\begin_document
\begin_header
\textclass scrbook
\begin_preamble
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\bibpunct{(}{)}{,}{a}{,}{,}
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}
\end_preamble
\use_default_options true
\maintain_unincluded_children false
\language american
\language_package default
\inputencoding auto
\fontencoding global


...
\bibtex_command bibtex
\index_command default
\paperfontsize default
\spacing single
\use_hyperref false

...

\cite_engine natbib
\cite_engine_type authoryear
\biblio_style apacite
\use_bibtopic false
\use_indices false
\paperorientation portrait

Comment: thank you very much. i hope that is right? i am so inexperienced with this

Comment: my friend tried the same at his mac also with apacite and natbib and gets the same problem. we dont find any solution. can anyone help us?

Comment: You can edit your question so that the MWE is in the question itself rather than a comment. You can then also use code markup to markup the MWE. I'm not really familiar with LyX or how it works, unfortunately, so I think it will have to be someone else who helps you.

Comment: @MargretMueller When you pasted into the comment, the example got cut short. Can you please repaste from the original .lyx file (into your question)? Also please mark it as "code".

Comment: I've formatted your code but, as others have said, it is incomplete. I also tried to format your English as English. Please bear in mind that the complete absence of appropriate capitalisation makes your question more difficult to read, especially for the many people who might be TeX experts but whose first language is not English. `i` is a Roman numeral. (There are also people who simply do not consider questions formatted without any attempt to format them as English.)

Answer (score 4):

You get this error if you load `natbib` additionally before `apacite`:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite} 

\begin{document}
bla
\end{document}
```

So don't load `natbib` but use only `\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}` (which will load natbib).

Comment: actually that is exactly what i did, it still showed the error all the time. what helped was swiching to apalike + natbib. this is what i did

\usepackage{natbib} \bibliographystyle{apalike} and ever since it all works very fine:-)

is it possible there is a general problem with natbib-apacite?

anyway thank you alot!

Comment: Well nobody knows what Lyx is doing here. Perhaps it is loading natbib always by default. You could export the code to latex to check. Perhaps you can change the loading order. If apacite is loaded first it should work. You could also inform the author of apacite. Beside this: natbib and apalike are rather outdated and more and more people are using biblatex instead.

Comment: dear ulrike, i changed it to natbib and apsr, but use bibtex - so i am new to this-how do i change it to biblatex (my new problem: will biblatex be able to understand hebrew?bibtex does not)

Comment: biblatex can handle utf8 and should be able to handle hebrew (but I'm not sure regarding the right to left writing, I never had to try it). I know that Lyx can use biblatex http://wiki.lyx.org/BibTeX/Biblatex. I don't know if lyx can handle hebrew (I'm not a lyx user), but I have some doubts if it is a good idea to use lyx if you want to use more than one script and writing directions: You would get more help if you had real code that you could show.